# How to make a number appear in a range from 0 to 9?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am currently completing a project and have come across an error in my coding.

I have a button which calls a JS prompt box asking to enter an integer between 0 and 9.

This number is then used as a game where 3 random integers from 0 and 9 appear every second and when you click on the matching number your score increases.

This is my code so far:

```
<script>

function chooseNum() 
{
var txt;
var person = prompt("Choose an integer between 0 and 9:");
if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
} else {
    txt = person;
}
document.getElementById("chosen").innerHTML = txt;
}

</script>
```

I want to know exactly how to display random integers in a range from 0 and 9.

Is a code like this on the right track?

```
<script>

var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber();},1000);

function randomNumber()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
$('#number1').html(rand);
}

</script>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Comment: document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = rand;

Comment: Yeah, FWIW `$('#number1')` is jQuery which apparently you're not using.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks heaps... btw can I have a button which functions to start the random number sequence I have?? Because the sequence starts automatically and I want to start it manually with a button input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var txt;

function chooseNum() 
{

var person = prompt("Choose an integer between 0 and 9:");
if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
} else {
    txt = person;
}

document.getElementById("chosen").innerHTML = txt;
}
chooseNum() ;
var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber();},1000);

function randomNumber()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* 9 + 1);
 $('#number1').html(rand);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="chosen"></p>
<p id="number1"></p>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the above code. Helped a tonne. In regards to the three numbers used, I wanted to create a game where the number selected in the prompt box matches the random numbers. For example.... if the user selects the number "6", and sees/clicks a 6 whenever in those three randomised numbers, the user gains one point. Hence if the user clicks on the wrong number, the game will deduct a point. There can be a negative score for the user. Any ideas on which approach I could take? Maybe a clickable link for each number? @vickypatel